# How to send files to website after needing to login in another url?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-requests

I am making a `Pyqt5` app and I'm trying now to make it post a file on my django website with a button click. I can make the script login to my site using `requests` with no problem (using csrftoken), but when uploading the file (to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking") it raises an *403 Forbidden Error* ("CSRF cookie not set.") even though I sent the csrftoken with the file.

Here is the code:

*send_file.py*

```
import requests

login_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/"
MAX_RETRIES = 2

client = requests.Session()
adapter = requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter(max_retries=MAX_RETRIES)
client.mount('http://', adapter) # I know that I should use https, but the server doesn't have it yet

client.get(login_url) # Goes to login page
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken'] # get csrf token
login_data = {'username': 'b','password':'senha123', 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken}

try:
    response = client.post(login_url, data=login_data) # executes login

    if "Logout from b" in str(response.content): # this is to confirm the user logged in

        print("Logged in at {}".format(response.url)) # "Logged in at http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/"
        response2 = client.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/') # Goes to the uploading page
        print("Logged in at {}".format(response2.url)) # "Logged in at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/"

        csrftoken1 = client.cookies['csrftoken'] # get another crsf token
        file_data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrftoken1}
        headers = {"Referer": 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/'}
        print(csrftoken, csrftoken1) # Both are different

        with open('Data\\training_data.npy', 'rb') as f:
            r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/', files={'training_data.npy': f}, data=file_data, headers=headers)
            print("File should be sent")
            print(r.text) # 403 Forbidden -> CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

    else:
        print("not logged in")

except Exception as e:
    print(e) # No errors raised
```

If you need to see the django models, templates or anything related to the website: [link](https://github.com/Setti7/Stardew-Web)

Comment: have you tried sending the (second) token on the headers? `X-CSRFToken`

Comment: @fixmycode like this? `headers = {"Referer": 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/', 'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken1}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post request that is sending the files is using a different session to the other requests, `requests.post`, and so won't have the cookie set.

Instead try `client.post`:

```
r = client.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/ranking/', files={'training_data.npy': f}, data=file_data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thanks! Also needed to change "training data.npy" to "file" (I think it is the html default name)